# Ошибка PDO HY000 1366 - Incorrect string value

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pdo

Изначальный код при котором все работает как положено. Есть некая строка `$finded`, делаю первую букву большой и добавляю в базу.

```
//делаем первую буква большой
$char = mb_strtoupper(substr($finded, 0, 2), "utf-8"); // это первый символ
$finded[0] = $char[0];
$finded[1] = $char[1]; //второй
//далее вставляем в базу
$this->db->insert($sql, $params);
```

Затем добавил чистку от множественных пробелов в `$finded` и PDO рапортует об ошибке, несовместимость кодировок видимо

```
array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(5) "HY000"
 [1]=> int(1366)
 [2]=> string(82) "Incorrect string value: '\x9E\xD1\x82\xD0\xBF\xD1...' for column 'status' at row 1"
}
```

Делается так перед кодом выше, модификатор `u` в регулярке не помогает

```
$finded = preg_replace('/\s\s+/isu', ' ', $finded);
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: Судя по этому `'\x9E\xD1\x82\xD0\xBF\xD` у вас первый байт `\xD0` потерян.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$finded = 'шел          по
                          лесу      ежик';

$finded = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($finded, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($finded, 1);
$finded = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $finded);

var_dump($finded);
```

Вернет

```
string 'Шел по лесу ежик' (length=29)
```

Comment: я неправильно понимаю количество символов в функциях `str` и `mb_` ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а вы уверены что первым символом у вас в строке всегда является двухбайтный? Зачем использовать функцию для однобайтных символов, если есть специальная функция для многобайтных?

Comment: изначально это было не мое)

Comment: сенкс. далее разберусь с многобайтными